# Database not updating - React.js, Moralis

Tags: reactjs, typescript, moralis

I'm having issues updating my database when saving edit. I am trying to retrieve Github data via API and with that data, add it to the Moralis database. I added another button outside of the form because I presume the saveEdit function will have to run after the form has been submitted. Code is as follows:

```
export const Dashboard = () => {
  const [userSearch, setUserSearch] = useState<string>("");
  const [foundUser, setFoundUser] = useState<IGitHubUser>();

  const performSearchRequest = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get<IGitHubUser>(
        `https://api.github.com/users/${userSearch}`
      );
      setFoundUser(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const searchForUser = (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    performSearchRequest();
  };

  const { Moralis, isInitialized } = useMoralis();

  const user = isInitialized ? Moralis.User.current() : undefined;

  const saveEdits = async () => {
    const User = Moralis.Object.extend("_User");
    const query = new Moralis.Query(User);
    const myDetails = await query.first();

    if (foundUser) {
      myDetails?.set("github", foundUser.name);
      console.log("details saved");
    }

    try {
      await myDetails?.save();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    window.location.reload();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Search for a user</h2>
      <form className="search-user" onSubmit={searchForUser}>
        <input
          value={userSearch}
          onChange={(e) => setUserSearch(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Enter a username..."
        />
        <button>Search</button>
      </form>
      <button onClick={saveEdits}>Search</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: And what is in a console?

Comment: @user4980215 what do you mean?

Comment: There are calls to `console.log(...)` in the code. What is the output?

Comment: @user4980215 console.log("details saved") logs "details saved" as it should which confuses me even more 